# Passing a page view model to a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a .net MVC page that has a form used to edit an entity from database. The form has some dynamic select list fields that need to be populated from Database also.

I pass a PageView Model that contains the Data for the entity, and a list of entities to populate the select list like so:

```
public class EditPortalPage
{
    public PortalViewModel Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cultures { get; set; }        
}
```

in my View I have

> @model Website.Models.Portals.EditPortalPage

at the top of the page

I can easily populate my form doing this:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Data.DefaultCultureId, new SelectList(Model.Cultures, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-info" })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data.DefaultCultureId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data.DefaultCultureId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The problem is this produces messed up Id and Name attributes for my form fields. In the above example it produces:

```
Name Field ID: Data_Name 
Name Field Name: Data.Name
```

What is the correct way to set it up so I the name and ID does not include the 'Data' prefix

Can I pass the Data model directly to teh form?

Comment: that is expected as name is used to bind the model object by ModelBinder, it would post back correct via form in the controller action

Comment: You could pass just the model itself to the form and then populate the select lists another way.  Possibly by creating helpers for them, or putting the data for them in the `ViewBag` and populating them from that.

Comment: Im trying to avoid using ViewBag and ViewData as ways of passing data to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HtmlHelper` methods generate the `name` and `id` attribute based on the name of the property. In your case, its a nested property so it generates the `Data.` prefix for the `name` attribute, and in the case of the `id` attribute, it replaces the `.`(dot) with an `_`(underscore) so that the `id` can be used in jquery selectors (otherwise the dot and the following text would be interpreted as a class selector.

Basing the `id` attribute on the property name ensures a unique `id` (and therefore valid html), and I'm not sure why you think its 'messed up', but you can always override the value by using

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Data.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "xxx",  @class = "form-control" } })
```

which will render `<input id="xxx" .... />` if you want to use `xxx` in a css or javascript/jquery selector (which is the only purpose of the `id` attribute)

However the `name` attribute is certainly not 'messed up' and if it were changed, it would not bind to your model when you submit. Under no circumstance should you ever attempt to change the `name` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

I'm guessing that your (incorrectly) using your data model as a parameter in the POST method, in which case you could use the `Prefix` property of the `[Bind]` attribute (although a `[Bind]` attribute should never be used with a view model)

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "Data")]PortalViewModel model)
```

to strip the `"Data."` prefix and bind to `PortalViewModel`.

However, the real issue here is you incorrect use of a view model. View models, especially when editing data, should not contain data models. They contain only the properties of your data model that you need in the view. Some of the benefits of view models include Separation of Concerns, protection against under and over posting attacks, ability to add display attributes which are not applicable in data models, and the ability to add additional view specific properties. In your case, you have negated all but the last point. You view model should be

```
public class EditPortalPage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Culture")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a culture")]
    public int? SelectedCulture { get; set; } //nullable and Required to protect against under-posting attacks
    ... // other properties of PortalViewModel that you need in the view
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cultures { get; set; }        
}
```

and in the POST method, you map your view model to the data model and save the data model. Refer also [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

As a side note, using `new SelctList(..)` in your `DropDownList()` method is pointless extra overhead - its just creating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one, and your code should just be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCulture, Model.Cultures, "Please select", new { ... })
```

Comment: Good advice and a thorough answer.

Comment: The problem is that I was creating a view model for each data model to achieve the benefits you highlighted in your answer, and then grouping them together in page models when I needed reference to one or more entities on a page. I guess I need to break that way of thinking and create single flat view models per page

Comment: If that is the case, then its fine because your not using data models in your views (although 'flatter' view models tend to be easier to work with). But because your have `@model EditPortalPage` in the view, then the parameter in the POST method should also be `EditPortalPage model`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the Q correctly, you could use a partial `"_data.cshtml"`:

```
@model PortalViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Pass data to the partial from your view:

```
@Html.Partial("_data",model.Data)
```

Comment: No, the example above was not complete, I would still need to pass the Select List data to the partial that you suggested. Ive updated my example to hopefully make it clearer. You can see that the Dropdown list options in the updated code needs to be populated from Model.Cultures, so I would still have to pass Model.Cultures and Model.Data to the partial

Comment: Couldnt you add `Enumerable<SelectListItem> Cultures` to `PortalViewModel`?

Comment: That is probably the best way to tackle it. Flatten everything into one view model. I had thought of that, but I wondered if I was missing something obvious.